# How to calculate the Class A network from a ip address and a subnet mask?

Tags: java, networking

I know classful networking is dead, but how would this be done?

If I have a ip address and a subnet mask, how can I calculate the Class A network? Is there a library in Java to do this?

Example IP: 142.163.79.8 
Example subnet mask: 255.0.0.0

Comment: There's the `&` operator...

Comment: Classful networking is dead, and it has been for over 20 years, killed in 1993 by RFCs [1518](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1518) and [1519](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1519), which defined CIDR (*Classless* Inter-Domain Routing). Please, let it rest in peace. Modern networking does not use classes.

Comment: If you want to learn subnetting, see [this excellent answer](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7117/8499) from the [Network Engineering SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) site. There is a section dealing with what you ask.

Comment: Your question embodies a redundancy. 255.0.0.0.0 *is* the class A subnet mask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

255.0.0.0 is a subnet mask for a class A network. In order to find the class A network take the logical and of the subnet mask and IP address. See: http://www.idc-online.com/technical_references/pdfs/data_communications/Subnet_Masks.pdf